# Java / or Android IP tunnel

Tags: java, android, ssh, tunnel

We need to tunnel a port on a cloud server to an Android device. Now, we're using a SSH client on Android (Jsch) to initiate a reverse port forward. This works, but we do not need / want the overhead of encryption / authentication.

Essentially, a simple IP tunnel that can be established from the client side (Android) to a server in the cloud.

Googling on this topic was not promising, so I thought I'd give it a try here and see if I can get any leads. Obviously we'd rather not build this ourselves from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually rather simple to implement in Java. The tunneler app on the device opens two connections, one to the server and one to the service on the device. Now if you use Input-/OutputStreams (as as ooposed to nio Channels) you need 2 threads that are each reading on one of the InputStreams and just write everything they received to the opposite output stream. On the server you will need a similar process that gets it's two connections from ServerSocket.accept and needs to be able to find out which one is the tunneler and which it a client of the service (i.e. tests for the header of the tunneled protocol on incoming connections).

This becomes a bit more complicated if you want to be able to tunnel multiple connections at the same time. You would need to implement some sort of protocol for this to be able to dispatch the tunneled packets to multiple connections on the device if you want to avoid to open multiple tunnel connections.

Comment: thanks for your comment. yes, that's what i need. i've been saying "multiplexed connections" ... one incoming port tunneled to many clients. i'll leave this open for a awhile to see if i can get any good leads on how to implement this. i'm definitely rusty on the topic.

Comment: i did end up writing a simplified version of this. i think getting it to be robust and stable, handle disconnects / reconnects, and so on is the troubling aspect. anyway, thanks.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need: I'm trying to access a device on my LAN from the Internet, but for some reason the device refuses to accept connections via the Internet despite port forwarding. I want to be able to tunnel connections through an Android device. I have already gotten as far as being able to access the Android device from the Internet, but I'm unable to find an app I can install on the android device to transparently tunnel to the actual device. Is the above answer an idea for an app that can be written, or does such an app already exist?